# List of objects, Need advice on how to organize them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I have a list of objects that looks like the below example:

```
[
  {time: 68, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 69, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 70, value: 361.81, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 68, value: 137.62, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 133.41, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 126.68, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 68, value: 172.22, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 147.03, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 173.11, metric: "flareTemp"}
]
```

basically its the value of "tubingPressure", "oilTemp" and "flareTemp"
at time 68s, 69s and 70s

I need to sort them together based on the time, so it will look like this,

`data = [
  {
    time:68,
    tubingpressure: 300,
    oilTemp: 137.62,
    flareTemp: 172.22
  },
  {
    time:69,
    tubingpressure: 300,
    oilTemp: 133.41,
    flareTemp: 147.03
  },
  {
    time:70,
    tubingpressure: 361.81,
    oilTemp: 126.68,
    flareTemp: 173.11
  }
]`

if we have a larger set of data (for example time from 68 to 5000), what are some better ways to deal with this problem?

I tried iterating the list over and over to group them, but I'm not sure if it is a good way in terms of performance.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do, but one method may be to make the time the key, so essentially

```data = { 68: { tubingpressure: 300, oilTemp: 137.62, flareTemp: 172.22 }, 69: { } ... }```

Keep in mind that ```for time in data``` doesn't always guarantee order, so you may want to setup another array to maintain order (basically an array of time) so that you can pull its values from the data list

Comment: you say group but your output example shows sorted list

Comment: Downvote because you did not show an attempt to solve this and stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [
  {time: 68, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 69, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 70, value: 361.81, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 68, value: 137.62, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 133.41, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 126.68, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 68, value: 172.22, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 147.03, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 173.11, metric: "flareTemp"}
];

const groupBy = key => array =>
  array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});
  
  
  const groupByTime = groupBy('time');
  
  
  console.log(
  JSON.stringify({
    objTime: groupByTime(obj)
  }, null, 1)
);
```

Comment: Can you explain what it's doing and why you chose this path?

Answer (score 0):

Use sort to sort your object, sort takes a callback with your condition.

> arr.sort([compareFunction])

```js
var obj = [
  {time: 68, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 69, value: 300, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 70, value: 361.81, metric: "tubingPressure"},
  {time: 68, value: 137.62, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 133.41, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 126.68, metric: "oilTemp"},
  {time: 68, value: 172.22, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 69, value: 147.03, metric: "flareTemp"},
  {time: 70, value: 173.11, metric: "flareTemp"}
];


console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1.forEach((obj) => {
    let object = newArr1.find(prevObj => prevObj.time === obj.time)
    let {metric,value,time} = obj;
    if(object){
        object[metric] = value;
    } else{
        let objectToPush = {
            time: time
        };
        objectToPush[metric] = value;
        newArr1.push(objectToPush)
    }
});
```